Get data from sunburst(plotly) by click event in R
Consider the following R code (Here you can find the source of the as.sunburstDF function.), I am trying to filter a dataframe by the current state of a sunburst plot in a shiny structure. This is my try:
library(shiny);library(dplyr); library(DT);library(plotly)
DF <- data.frame(x=rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=4),
                 y=rep(letters[3:4],each=2,length=8),
                 z=rep(letters[5:6],length=8),
                 fn=c(108, 143, 102, 300, 320, 500, 37,  90))
as.sunburstDF <- function(DF, value_column = NULL, add_root = FALSE){
  require(data.table)
  colNamesDF <- names(DF)
  if(is.data.table(DF)){
    DT <- copy(DF)
  } else {
    DT <- data.table(DF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  if(add_root){
    DT[, root := "Total"]  
  }
  colNamesDT <- names(DT)
  hierarchy_columns <- setdiff(colNamesDT, value_column)
  DT[, (hierarchy_columns) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = hierarchy_columns]
  
  if(is.null(value_column) && add_root){
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", colNamesDF))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && !add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c(setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  }
  hierarchyList <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(hierarchy_columns)){
    current_columns <- colNamesDT[1:i]
    if(is.null(value_column)){
      currentDT <- unique(DT[, ..current_columns][, values := .N, by = current_columns], by = current_columns)
    } else {
      currentDT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by=current_columns, .SDcols = "values"]
    }
    setnames(currentDT, length(current_columns), "labels")
    hierarchyList[[i]] <- currentDT
  }
  hierarchyDT <- rbindlist(hierarchyList, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  parent_columns <- setdiff(names(hierarchyDT), c("labels", "values", value_column))
  hierarchyDT[, parents := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(all(is.na(x)), yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[!is.na(x)], sep = ":", collapse = " - "))}), .SDcols = parent_columns]
  hierarchyDT[, ids := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " - ")}), .SDcols = c("parents", "labels")]
  hierarchyDT[, c(parent_columns) := NULL]
  return(hierarchyDT)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 4,plotlyOutput("distPlot"))
        ,
        column(width = 4, DT::DTOutput("dt_f"))
        ,
        column(width = 4,DT::DTOutput("dt_f_sb"))
      )
      ,
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 4,htmlOutput("hoverDataOut"))
        ,
        column(width = 4,htmlOutput("clickDataOut"))
      )
    )
)    
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dt_f <- renderDT({
    #browser()
    event_data <- event_data(event = "plotly_sunburstclick", source = "sunSource", priority = "event")
    DF_SB <- as.sunburstDF(DF)
    #browser()
    ids_1 <- DF_SB[event_data$pointNumber, ]$ids
    ret = tryCatch({
      filtered_df <- DF
      str=stringr::str_split(ids_1," - ")[[1]]
      for(i in 1:length(str)){
        filtered_df<-filtered_df %>% filter(.[[i]] == str[i])
      }
      filtered_df
    },  error = function(error_condition) {
      DF
    })
  return(ret)
  })
  output$dt_f_sb <- renderDT({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    as.sunburstDF(DF)
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    plot_ly(data = as.sunburstDF(DF, value_column = "fn", add_root = TRUE),
            ids = ~ids, labels= ~labels, source = "sunSource",
            parents = ~parents, values= ~values, 
            type='sunburst', branchvalues = 'total') 
  })
  hoverData <- reactive({
    currentEventData <- unlist(event_data(event = "plotly_hover", source = "sunSource", priority = "event"))
  })      
  clickData <- reactive({
    currentEventData <- unlist(event_data(event = "plotly_sunburstclick", source = "sunSource", priority = "event"))
  })      
  output$hoverDataOut <- renderText({
    paste("Hover data:", paste(names(hoverData()), unlist(hoverData()), sep = ": ", collapse = " | "))
  })      
  output$clickDataOut <- renderText({
    paste("Click data:", paste(names(clickData()), unlist(clickData()), sep = ": ", collapse = " | "))
  })
} 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The aim is to retrieve data from a sunburst plot through a click event in R to filter a dataframe within a shiny framework. The main issue in the provided code is that filtering does not work correctly when reverting back to a previous state.
The "str" variable tracks the click event and get the parents.  Then try to filter the dataframe based on it! But unfortunately
It does not work perfectly when draw back. How to fix it?
